# Fibrations from parametric monads

Tags: ct.category-theory

Every functor $F : {\cal C}\times{\cal X} \to {\cal X}$ determines a "parametric family" of endofunctors on $\cal X$ by transposition $\hat F : {\cal C} \to {\sf Cat}({\cal X},{\cal X})$.

Consider the correspondence sending $C\in\cal C$ to the category ${\cal X}^{F_C}$ of algebras for $F_C : {\cal X} \to {\cal X}$; this is the object part of a contravariant pseudofunctor:

$$ {\cal C}^{op} \to {\sf Cat} : C\mapsto {\cal X}^{F_C}$$

As such, this determines a fibration over ${\cal C}$. If $F_C$ is not only an endofunctor but a monad, moreover, I can perform the same construction sending $C$ to either the Eilenberg-Moore category of $F_C$, or the Kleisli category of $F_C$. Similarly, I can reason with coalgebras, coEilenberg-Moore and Kleisli for a comonad (obtaining covariant pseudofunctors sometimes, and thus opfibrations; but the idea does not change).

A specific example of this construction is the "[simple fibration](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0049237X98800311)" associated with a cartesian category $\cal B$, generated when this construction is applied to the comonad $\_\times I$: each fiber of the simple fibration is the "simple slice" ${\cal B}/\!\!/B$. Gluing together the Eilenberg-Moore categories instead one obtain the usual slice category. (This is an exercise in Jacobs' book on categorical logic).

Given this construction seems very general and pliable, and "rediscovers" at least two important examples of fibrations.

Does it have a name, are there other remarkable examples?